# Biber does not start

Tags: biber

I'm working on a portable version of MikTeX and TeXstudio.

When I try to run Biber, the following error occurs:

> ..\MikTeX\miktex\bin\biber.exe: extraction of C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\par-55383237353136\cache-19a661c7206c3f371c207b98ac69231301395587/biber.exe (custom Perl interpreter) failed (errno=13)

The same error occurs when I start biber on the Command Line.
pdfLaTeX on the other hand works fine.

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: You could try to set `PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP` to some other folder. See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

biber needs to "unpack" itself. In restricted environments the standard location (in the user temp-folder) is perhaps not accessible. In such cases you can set the `PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP` to some other folder. See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/70